# Covertir color RGBA a HEXADECIMAL con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hola amigos tengo este script donde obtengo el color rgba de una imagen, pero necesito convertirlo en hexadecimal y guardarlo en una variable

```
const img= document.getElementById('imagen');
const output= document.getElementById('output');

img.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  let ctx;
  if(!this.canvas) {
      this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      this.canvas.width = this.width;
      this.canvas.height = this.height;
      ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  } else {

    ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');

  }

  const pixel = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

  output.innerHTML ='R: ' + pixel[0] + '<br>G: ' + pixel[1] +
      '<br>B: ' + pixel[2] + '<br>A: ' + pixel[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `toString(16)` asi:

```js
const gatete= document.getElementById('gato');
const output= document.getElementById('output');

gatete.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  let ctx;
  if(!this.canvas) {
      this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      this.canvas.width = this.width;
      this.canvas.height = this.height;
      ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  } else {
    ctx=this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  }
  const pixel = ctx.getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
        
  output.innerHTML ='#' + pixel[0].toString(16) + pixel[1].toString(16) +
       pixel[2].toString(16);
                
});
```

```css
img,pre {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img id="gato" src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" crossorigin="anonymous">

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando obtengas el color `rgba` llamas a la función rgba2hex() que te coloco abajo:

```js
function rgba2hex(orig) {
  var a, isPercent,
    rgb = orig.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/^rgba?\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),?([^,\s)]+)?/i),
    alpha = (rgb && rgb[4] || "").trim(),
    hex = rgb ?
    (rgb[1] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
    (rgb[2] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) +
    (rgb[3] | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1) : orig;

  if (alpha !== "") {
    a = alpha;
  } else {
    a = 01;
  }
  // Multiplicación antes de convertir a HEX
  a = ((a * 255) | 1 << 8).toString(16).slice(1)
  hex = hex + a;

  return hex;
}

function test(colorcode) {
  console.log(colorcode, rgba2hex(colorcode));
}

test("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74)");
test("rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)");
test("rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
test("rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)");
```

La notación `rgba()` se expresa como un valor de 0 ~ 1, debe multiplicarlo por 255 antes de intentar convertirlo a su forma HEX.

Pero tenga en cuenta que esta es solo una de las notaciones rgba y que, por ejemplo, fallará con la notación basada en porcentaje.
Tenga en cuenta también que todos los navegadores no admiten la notación HEX de RGBA, por lo que es posible que prefiera otro método para convertir sus valores en función de lo que quiera hacer con ellos.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49974627/10158153).

Comment: Cual seria la mejor opcion que funcione en la mayoria de navegadores?